# Setting up CUPS server on port 80

Tags: networking, debian, cups

Would it be advisable to use port 80 instead of the default CUPS port 631 or the alternative port 49631 as adviced by [Debian SystemPrinting](https://wiki.debian.org/SystemPrinting).

I could bind it to another virtual interface with a seperate IP address so it wouldn't conflict with my existing web servers listening on port 80.

My goal would be using a simple URL so that the users would be able to add the printer without remembering the port, as that would be too complicated for them. I already have a unbound server and dnsmasq on my printer server so I wouldn't have any problems pointing the printer domain to its IP address.

Instead of my current configuration

```
http://192.168.1.101:49631/printers/PRINTER_1
```

Could I use instead with

```
http://cups.domain.tech/printers/PRINTER_1
```

Comment: I'd just set up reverse proxying from `cups.domain.tech:80` to `192.168.1.101:49631` and call it a day—you will have it both in its "standard" location and in a convenient place.